# Neovim LSP: pyright server does not dynamically regognize changes in sub folders

Tags: python-3.x, lua, neovim, pyright

I setup Neovim LSP using the [nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig) and the [lsp-installer](https://github.com/williamboman/nvim-lsp-installer) where I also installed the `pyright` server.

Without any further configuration it worked out of the box. However when I have a class in a subfolder and add a new method, pyright does not recognize this method when I want to access it in a different file. When I restart neovim, or open and close the file, pyright suddenly recognizes the newly added method.

I also tried `:LspRestart` with no effect.

I tried to add some settings to the pyright server:

```
return {
    settings = {
  python = {
    analysis = {
      autoSearchPaths = true,
      diagnosticMode = "workspace",
      useLibraryCodeForTypes = true,
    }
  }

    },
}
```

But this also had no effect.

`:LspLog` also does not show anything which could point to the issue:

```
[START][2022-07-15 11:11:05] LSP logging initiated
[WARN][2022-07-15 11:11:09] ...lsp/handlers.lua:109 "The language server pyright triggers a registerCapability handler despite dynamicRegistration set to false. Report upstream, this warning is harmless"
[WARN][2022-07-15 11:11:09] ...lsp/handlers.lua:456 "stubPath typings is not a valid directory."
[WARN][2022-07-15 11:11:20] ...lsp/handlers.lua:109 "The language server pyright triggers a registerCapability handler despite dynamicRegistration set to false. Report upstream, this warning is harmless"
```

I also could not find any setting regarding to this issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/settings.md) which could solve this.

Since I am new to python, the way I import and structure classes might not be common and might be an issue which could cause this problem.

- As a main entry point I have `main.py` in the root folder
- All other source files are in a `program/` folder which does not have a `__init__.py`
- Inside `program/` there are folders which each have a `__init__.py` file f.e. `core/`

`core/__init__.py`:

```
from .myClass import myClass
```

and in `main.py` I import it like this:

```
from subfolder.core import myClass
myClass.newMethod() # this is only recognized by lsp/pyright after the file is closed and reopen
```

Is the issue a bug in pyright (not likely I guess), a missing setting or my strange folder/import structure?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am experiencing the same problem, and it's annoying to have to close neovim and reopen it after creating a new file.
I previously used coc-pyright, and this wasn't an issue (I appreciate that they are not the same). Perhaps some sort of file watcher needs to be enabled...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this: create (or modify) pyproject.toml, put it in the project root directory. Inside pyproject.toml, add the following lines:

```
[tool.pyright]
extraPaths = ["program/core" ,"program/directory_2", "program/directory_3"]
```

The idea is that you have to add the sub directories manually, which is really tedious but at least it works in my case.